Web package upgrade, blob download not working as before
I am trying to update my app from dart:html to package:web
I had this function:
var blob = html.Blob([data], 'text/plain', 'native');
  html.AnchorElement(href: html.Url.createObjectUrlFromBlob(blob))
    ..setAttribute('download', filename)
    ..click()
    ..remove();

and updated it to this:
  final blob = web.Blob(
    [data.buffer.toJS].toJS,
    web.BlobPropertyBag(type: 'text/plain', endings: 'native'),
  );
  web.HTMLAnchorElement()
    ..href = web.URL.createObjectURL(blob)
    ..setAttribute('download', filename)
    ..click()
    ..remove();

data is a Uint8List
But the excel I want to download says it is corrupted and needs to be fixed to work.
After letting it fix itself the data still seems correct and I confirmed the download worked correctly before.
Any idea why the resulting file would be broken?
